# Magento 'Featured Categories' Images Not Loading on Frontend

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In my Magento (1.9.3.3) Admin panel, I have images uploaded for each category, and I'm able to see them from the category edit form. However, on the front-end homepage, my featured images are not showing. If I inspect the home page, each category image src is blank:

```
<img alt="" src="">
```

The code that generates this is as follows:

```
<?php
$_subcategories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
->addAttributeToSort( 'feature_position'); 

$_subcategories->getSelect()->limit(7,0);

$categories_count = count($_subcategories);
?>

<div class="row">
<?php 
$count = 0;
if($_subcategories): ?>
<ul id="myList">
    <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $cat): 
        $count = $count + 1; 
        if( $count > 6 ) {
            break;
        }
    ?>
        <li class="col-md-4 cat-item col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="display: list-item;">
            <a class="image-link" href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl($cat);?>"><div class="feature-cat"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl();?>">
                <div class="feature-cat-name"><?php echo $cat->getname(); ?></div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

So, the final HTML output for each category looks like this:

```
<a class="image-link" href="http://127.0.0.1/product-category/product1">
    <div class="feature-cat"><img alt="" src="">
        <div class="feature-cat-name">Batteries</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Any ideas what $cat->getImageUrl() is coming back NULL, but all the other category attributes are fine? I've tried a number of things with no success. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also add below attribute to filters and then try.

```
$_subcategories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
->addAttributeToSort( 'feature_position')
->addAttributeToSelect('image');
```

Then get the image for each category in for loop.

```
foreach($_subcategories as $subcat) {
echo "Image : ".$subcat->getImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if($_category->getImageUrl()){
$catimg = $_category->getImageUrl(); 
}else{
$catimg=null;
continue;
```

Or just

```
$catimg = $_category->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$_subcategories = 
    Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort( 'feature_position')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('notnull' => true));
```